# how do I create a funded account to use my local nearup docker container for development

Tags: docker, blockchain, account, near

I am a bit new to this whole blockchain thing. Am successfully running `nearup` (https://github.com/near/nearup)(the docker version).

Using NEAR's `near-cli` even specifying `localnet` still creates wallet and accounts at their `testnet`.  Can't seem to get the `near-cli` to connect to my docker container.

I also tried building/using `near-wallet` (https://github.com/near/near-wallet) but ran into many problems (dont remember specifics but I think it was build problems).

Is there a way to use the `near-api-js` to create a funded account to use with my `localnet`?

The documentation doesn't seem very good, it's all over the place and some seems out-of-date.

Any help appreciated.

#### UPDATE: 2022-08-13:

I followed the instructions watching the suggested video as well as https://docs.near.org/develop/testing/kurtosis-localnet.

Similar issues as when I tried Kurtosis previously.

Here are all the exact steps and results:

```
# we are in the near-kurtosis-module repository directory
# -L follow redirects
# -o output response of url to file
# --url the URL we're going to request from
curl -L \
-o ~/launch-local-near-cluster.sh \
--url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kurtosis-tech/near-kurtosis-module/master/launch-local-near-cluster.sh

bash ~/launch-local-near-cluster.sh

WARN[2022-08-13T16:54:19-04:00] You are running an old version of the Kurtosis CLI; we suggest you to update it to the latest version, '0.23.2'
WARN[2022-08-13T16:54:19-04:00] You can manually upgrade the CLI tool following these instructions: + errors so we go to URL below to update the CLI https://docs.kurtosistech.com/installation.html#upgrading-kurtosis-cli
```

(plus a bunch of errors)
So I go to the above suggested link and follow more instructions:

```
echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://apt.fury.io/kurtosis-tech/ /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurtosis.list

sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade

sudo apt install kurtosis-cli

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
kurtosis-cli is already the newest version (0.23.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I try again:

```
bash ~/launch-local-near-cluster.sh

Error: An error occurred running the pre-validation-and-run function
 --- at /home/circleci/project/cli/command_framework/lowlevel/lowlevel_kurtosis_command.go:274 (LowlevelKurtosisCommand.MustGetCobraCommand.func2) ---
Caused by: An error occurred getting an engine manager.
 --- at /home/circleci/project/cli/command_framework/highlevel/engine_consuming_kurtosis_command/engine_consuming_kurtosis_command.go:107 (EngineConsumingKurtosisCommand.getSetupFunc.func1) ---
Caused by: An error occurred getting the Kurtosis config
 --- at /home/circleci/project/cli/helpers/engine_manager/engine_manager.go:84 (NewEngineManager) ---
Caused by: An error occurred getting or initializing the Kurtosis config
 --- at /home/circleci/project/cli/helpers/engine_manager/engine_manager.go:366 (getKurtosisConfig) ---
Caused by: An error occurred executing init interactive config
 --- at /home/circleci/project/cli/kurtosis_config/kurtosis_config_provider.go:36 (KurtosisConfigProvider.GetOrInitializeConfig) ---
Caused by: The Kurtosis config isn't initialized so we'd initialize it interactively here except STDOUT isn't a terminal (indicating that this is probably running in CI) which means that you'll need to manually initialize the config using the instructions here: https://docs.kurtosistech.com/running-in-ci.html
 --- at /home/circleci/project/cli/kurtosis_config/kurtosis_config_initializer.go:26 (initInteractiveConfig) ---
Error: An error occurred executing module 'kurtosistech/near-kurtosis-module'
```

Comment: Just start the "kurtosis" engine using: `kurtosis engine start`

Answer (score 0):

You should use Kurtosis for local development the docs of which can be found here:
https://docs.near.org/develop/testing/kurtosis-localnet

Short video going trough it:
https://www.loom.com/share/8a1b8e2138334a81a380f5d523fba27e

When running you will be given an keypair to test.near account which has tons of nears at your disposal.

It is worth noting that in order to start building and exploring smart contracts on near you do not have to run a localnet. You can build and deploy contracts on to testnet. To learn more about smart contract development you can check the https://docs.near.org/develop/quickstart-guide

Comment: hi, thank you, yes, previously i had already created wallet/account and deployed a contract on testnet, but this time I do want to do the same on localnet.

Comment: I did try kurtosis, and had issues but will take another look at the links you sent.  thanks.